# Check if DateTime value is today, tomorrow or later

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an object attribute of the DateTime class.

How would I understand if the saved date is today, tomorrow or else later?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here are some useful ways to achieve it:

```
datetime = DateTime.now  => Sun, 26 Oct 2014 21:00:00

datetime.today? # => true
datetime.to_date.past? # => false (only based on date)
datetime.to_date.future? # => false  (only based on date)

datetime.to_date == Date.tomorrow # => false
datetime.to_date == Date.yesterday # => false
```

Comment: This was probably in the context of a loaded ActiveSupport gem. There is no `today?` in the standard library.

Comment: This is from Active Support but can also be used outside of Rails: `require 'active_support/core_ext/time/calculations'` (see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html)

Answer (score 8):

Something like...

```
datetime = Time.now.to_datetime
=> Sun, 26 Oct 2014 16:24:55 -0600 

datetime >= Date.today
=> true

datetime < Date.tomorrow
=> true

datetime += 1.day
=> Mon, 27 Oct 2014 16:25:12 -0600

datetime >= Date.today
=> true

datetime >= Date.tomorrow
=> true 

datetime < (Date.tomorrow + 1.day)
=> false
```

?

Comment: I though you nailed it but.. hm. In short I'd love the following to be true, but it isn't.. `DateTime.current == Date.current`

Comment: `DateTime.current.to_date == Date.current`?

Comment: Of course! :)  (Just remove the dot in the DateTime class..)

Comment: Oops -- yup -- fixed!

Answer (score 4):

#### yesterday? & tomorrow? (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 adds new [`#yesterday?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-yesterday-3F) and [`#tomorrow?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-tomorrow-3F) methods to Date and Time classes.

As a result, now, your problem can be solved as:

```rb
datetime = DateTime.current
# => Mon, 16 Nov 2020 20:50:16 +0000


datetime.today?
# => true

datetime.yesterday?
# => false

datetime.tomorrow?
# => false
```

It is also worth to mention that [`#yesterday?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-yesterday-3F) and [`#tomorrow?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-tomorrow-3F) are aliased to [`#prev_day?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-prev_day-3F) and [`#next_day?`](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateAndTime/Calculations.html#method-i-next_day-3F).

Here is [a link to the corresponding PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/37625).